# DIY Build Config Transform

Tags: xml, build, transform, config

I'll ask this, but I'll be perfectly fine with someone pointing me to another post/question if it's already been asked and answered.

I want to something like the Config Transformation, but I can't use that particular VS extension because my project does not have 'app.config' in the project. Instead it has myfunction.dll.config as an element of the solution.  I've already coded to look for myfunction.dll.config and read it appropriately, but now I need to fix some build changes so that a Release build can made by another team *without editing the config file* before they move it to the final destination for a production/live environment.

I want to put similar tags in a myfunction.dll.debug.config and myfunction.dll.release.config and have the build create the appropriate myfunction.dll.config in the Debug or Release folder.

I apologize that I'm not as familiar with xml transforms in a generic sense as I should be, but I learn pretty quickly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my question came just 10 minutes before I 'Googled' around enough to find my own answer at https://ctt.codeplex.com/ .  Hate it when that happens.  Now if I can get the post-build script to run it correctly, I'll be in business.